# how to test for simple http server

Tags: c, httpserver

I am trying to test a small nonpersisten http server I have written in c. The problem is that when I try to test it I can not bind the socket (80) to the port. eg(I try to reach my pc trough localhost and then I specify the port; localhost:port). I get error Address already in use. I if I try to reach the pc trough another port say localhost:7000 then I am able to bind and the program runs but then the page does not load and I am unable to send the contents.

Edit: I am using Ubuntu.

```
 port = 6788;

 fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 


  memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))
  listen(fd,3);


  (inf loop)
  {
        afd =  accept(......); 
   .
   .
   .  
  }
```

Comment: are you in linux? in linux you need run the application with sudo

Comment: 80 port problem. Discover which daemon is already listening to 80 port with netstat -ab (windows) or netstat -apn (linux).

Comment: yes, sorry ubuntu. I did run with sudo

Comment: Just to make sure I got you right: For the client you try to `bind` the socket? This would be wrong. For the client you have to invoke `connect`. The purpose of `bind` is to create server sockets not client sockets.

Comment: could you post some of your code?

Comment: To avoid this problems, always use a port number above 1024: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: I have apache installed. Coudl taht be a problem?

Comment: Why does he need a root access?

Comment: absolutely. apache binds to port 80 by default (just like any other http server)

Comment: @AdelQodmani, "low" ports (up to 1024) are root-only ("administrator privilege required").

Comment: I see, where can I place the html file so that it does not interfere with port 80 and I get to access it by localhost?

Comment: you say if you run in another port diferent of port 80, is able but not load page, post the code, to check it

Comment: @vonbrand and lindosekai : thanks :D

Comment: @lindosekai Sorry, I have posted the code.

Comment: well in it's code part you posted are good, the problem may be is the accpet-client loop, whats happend when a client is connected to the server... al code...

Comment: The *port already in use* problem is obviously due to Apache, only one application may bind and listen to a port. The port 7000 problem is due to the code that is not shown in your question (server *and* client).